# removing columns from jqgrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, jqgrid-php, jqgrid-formatter

I would like to add my own column names in jqgrid and also i want to prevent the column names that is automatically added by php-jqgrid according to sql query.

I am using php-jqgrid.

Actually jqgrid getting the column name from mysql table's column name and my db table has about 55 column, but all columns are necessary for further calculations . so i want to just print only 12 selected columns not all other rest columns.

I am disabling other column like this :-

```
$grid->setColProperty("lat", array("hidden"=>true));
$grid->setColProperty("lng", array("hidden"=>true));
$grid->setColProperty("clinic_id", array("hidden"=>true));
$grid->setColProperty("id", array("hidden"=>true));
.....
.....
.....
```

But it is complex to set every column hidden/disable. Requires code for every column set to hidden/disable.

Is there any sort method to hide/disable rest columns form grid.

I am using this code to do that, but its also getting the name of columns which i have not declare in the method $grid->setColModel(null, null, $mylabels);

Can anyone please tell me what short code i should to write for removing extra added column in jqgrid.

Thanks a lot.

```
require_once '/var/www/html/zbajtmp/public/jqgrid/jq-config.php';
// include the jqGrid Class
require_once "/var/www/html/zbajtmp/public/jqgrid/php/jqGrid.php";
// include the driver class
require_once "/var/www/html/zbajtmp/public/jqgrid/php/jqGridPdo.php";
// Connection to the server
$conn = new PDO(DB_DSN,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD);
// Tell the db that we use utf-8
$conn->query("SET NAMES utf8");

// Create the jqGrid instance
$grid = new jqGridRender($conn);
 // Write the SQL Query
//$grid->SelectCommand = 'SELECT OrderID, OrderDate, CustomerID, Freight, ShipName  FROM orders';
$grid->SelectCommand = 'SELECT *  FROM clinic';
// set the ouput format to json
$grid->dataType = 'json';
// Let the grid create the model
//$grid->setColModel();
$mylabels = array(
"clinic_name"=>"Clinic ame",
"clinic_address"=>"Address",
"HomePhone"=>"Home Phone",
"WorkPhone"=>"Work Phone",
"Email_Id"=>"Email",
);
// Let the grid create the model with the desired labels
$grid->setColModel(null, null, $mylabels);

$grid->setColProperty("lat", array("hidden"=>true));
$grid->setColProperty("lng", array("hidden"=>true));
$grid->setColProperty("clinic_id", array("hidden"=>true));
$grid->setColProperty("id", array("hidden"=>true));
.....
.....
.....
// Set the url from where we obtain the data
//$grid->setUrl('/var/www/html/zbajtmp/application/views/scripts/clinic/grid.php');
$grid->setUrl('http://sunlinux/zbajtmp/application/views/scripts/clinic/grid.php');
// Set grid caption using the option caption
$grid->setGridOptions(array(
    "caption"=>"This is my custom Caption...",
    "rowNum"=>50,
    "sortname"=>"id",
    "hoverrows"=>true,
    "rowList"=>array(20,50,100,1000),
    "width"=>"100%",
    "height"=>350,
"footerrow"=>true,
"rownumbers"=>true,
"multiselect"=>true,
"altRows"=>true,
"altclass"=>'clsalt',
"loadtext"=>"<div class='loadingbox'>Please wait. Loading...</div>",

    ));


$grid->renderGrid('#grid','#pager',true, null, null, true,true);


$conn = null;
```

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

jqGrid builds the `colModel` using the `selectCommand` - so you will need to hide the extra columns that are not required for rendering manually - i suggest you remove the `*` from the `select` statement and just select the columns you require.